# IPv6 Passwordless login

Tags: networking, ipv6

Me and my friends are currently working at creating an IPv6 network in our school. It's a thesis, so we have a teacher that helps us finding out what we have to do. Lately he said, that ipv6 enables user to login passwordless. I don't know what he meant with that, but he said that if a user logs in on a specific computer, he can gain access to all of his accounts passwordless just by logging in into his computer. I mean, would it theretically work? I don't think it's possible with ipv6, but what do i know. Can you please help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is confusing password less accounts can be done with IPv4. Sounds like you should ask your professor for additional help

Answer (score 3):

What your teacher is describing is Single Sign On (SSO). It has nothing to do with the layer 3 network protocol used. The technologies are orthogonal.

Either your teacher is really confused, or he's trying to confuse you   Read up on SSO and demonstrate your ability to do independent research to your teacher!

Comment: Yeah so I asked him again and he said, that if we creste a vpn server we can connect to it without typing the usernam and password every time.  Is it possible?